# Google Chart API loading

Tags: html, google-visualization, geomap

As you may know the Google GeoMap (flash version) loads pretty slow. I've created a statistics menu having like 3 or 4 tabs, in each of them I have some statistics (line chart and pie chart load instantly). So I thought: I'll simply place the GeoMap Chart into a background tab so until the user gets there it will be loaded.

The question: Why doesn't the API load the GeoMap chart if the div in which is shown is hidden (display:none) ?

Answer (score 3):

> Graphs will render incorrectly (often extremely small/close to
>   invisible) if rendered in a hidden element. You need to redraw the
>   graph after making the element visible.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600892/401554