# Using .hide() and .show() with Google Visualization

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have created a line graph with google visualization.  I have tested it and it works as expected.  The problem is when I start the page with .hide() on the visualization and then click the button to show it, it will not display the visualization.  Here is a cut down version of what I have.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#visualization').hide();
        $('#show').click(function() {
            $('#visualization').show();
        });
        $('#hide').click(function() {
            $('#visualization').hide();
        });

    });
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart','annotatedtimeline']});
// Begin Annoted Time Line Chart - 1
      function drawVisualization() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Users');
          //data.addColumn('string', 'title1');
          data.addRows(10);
data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2011, 11 ,1));
          data.setValue(0, 1, 21);
          data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2011, 11 ,2));
          data.setValue(1, 1, 24);
// Do this for the rest of the chart

...
var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
              document.getElementById('visualization'));
          annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true});
        }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
<body>
<a href="#" id="show">show</a> <a href="#" id="hide">hide</a>
    <div style="border:solid">
                <div id="visualization" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        </div>
</body>
```

If I comment out the .hide() at the beginning the 2 buttons to show and hide work fine, but when its initially hidden it does not work. I have tried placing the code for the visualization above the query part but it still will not work.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Craig

EDIT

I was able to use this
     setTimeout(function(){
                  $('#tabs').tabs(); // or hide()
                  }, 50); 
            });

Comment: I don't know about this code specifically, but there is code that detects when it is hidden and does not do it's work when that's the case.  This is often done for efficiency reasons so lots of CPU or memory isn't wasted when the object is hidden.  To work around that issue, you'd have to render it after making it visible rather than before.

Answer (score 5):

Gviz graphs will render incorrectly (often extremely small/close to invisible) if rendered in a hidden element. You need to redraw the graph after making the element visible.

A simple example of doing this, based on your code, would be something along the lines of adding your draw function to the callback of the show handler:

```
$('#visualization').show(function() {
    drawVisualization();
});
```

The callback will be executed once the show is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the advice provided by Oli above, but the re-drawing did not work out for me on Chrome.

A better approach for me was to define the height and width in the chart with fixed numbers.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart describes the options.

I simply used this and it works:

```
   var options = {
      title: '<%= t("views.participants.ranking.s23") %>',
      colors:['#3f3f3f', '#199EDA'],
      chartArea: {top: 30, left: 80, width: 490, height: 300},
      height: 500,
      width: 710,
      legend: {position: 'right', alignment: 'start'},
      sizeAxis: {maxSize: 20}
      }
```

Comment: I know this is a old thread.. But I did as you suggested. It works okay. But the data on y-axis isn't showing. Did you have that problem? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: No, gave up on the whole project, company failed, doing something else now.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for responding.